# Can i use phabricator in Ubuntu without the support of mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, lamp, phabricator

I am bit confused about the installation of phabricator

In every sites they mentioned it like for installing Phabricator i need a prerequisite of PHP5 and mysql

```
But i already have Oracle SQL can i do it without installing MYSQL....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - **MySQL:** You need MySQL.
>
> https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/installation_guide/

The manual says you **need** MySQL. So you probably **need** MySQL. Oracle and MySQL (or most other database systems) aren't 100% cross compatible. Phabricator was written for MySQL, period.